# How to print all the columns in single line from dataframe on Jenkins console?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
 I have created a data frame which contains lot of columns:
    
    for eg.
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col4 col5 col6 col7
    
    and each row contains plenty of data in it.
    
    I tried this:
```

pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 200)

```
    and in output I am getting:
    
    col1   col2 col3 col4
    col5    col6
    row1   row1 row1 row1
    row1   row1..
    
    
    But I want all this to printed on single line in Jenkins console.
    
    

 col1   col2  col3   col4  col5  col6

 row1   ro1   row1   row1  row1  row1

    
    
    also I see some of the rows which have too much of that comes like row.....
    how can print the full data.
```

Comment: Can you post a [mre] including the actual and expected/preferred output?

Answer (score 0):

you could use to_string

```
print(data_frame[row:row].to_string())
```

Comment: I am still getting the same output which I was getting before with other 3 options.

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer. Please explain your answer/implementation.